# How to automatically close my GUI application from within?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-shell

Let me explain my question with an example. In my app, I need to provide a way to automatically close it from within "itself." (An example of such function is when an installer/updater of my app needs it to close before installing an update. Another example is when my app performs actions on schedule and needs to automatically close once it's done.)

I picture that in the simplest situation posting the `WM_CLOSE` message to the own window will accomplish this task, but there're the following cases that will not work with just that:

- My app may be displaying an arbitrary number of child dialog windows.
- My app may be displaying a common control window, such as Open File dialog:

[image]

or this one, but there could be others:

[image]

- And lastly what could one do if the close button is not even available:

[image]

At the current point, I simply resort to terminating my process (either with the `exit()` method from within, or with `TerminateProcess` from outside.)

But I'm curious, if there's a more *graceful* way of closing my GUI app (from within)?

Comment: `PostQuitMessage`. If your dialog message pumps are correct they will close their dialog and then re-post `WM_QUIT` for the next message pump up the call stack.

Comment: Do you really want to do this when arbitrary modal dialogs are showing? And which thread is going to invoke the shutdown? Posting `WM_QUIT` will get it done, but think about which code can reasonably post that.

Comment: Thank you, both. @DavidHeffernan all the worker threads will be closed gracefully from the WM_DESTROY notification processor. The question is, would `PostQuitMessage` invoke it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: And forgot to say -- I can post it from any thread. Would from the main thread work?

Comment: How are you going to do it from the main thread when the main thread is in a common file dialog modal message loop?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: OK, good point, I can't. How else can I do it then?

Comment: What if the dialog is shown part way through a process that should be completed before the app terminates?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I can create a method that will gracefully stop all worker threads and other background processes. My concern is closing the UI/windows that I listed above.

Comment: Posting `WM_QUIT` to the main thread will close all the modal dialogs, so long as they are coded correctly, but you might want to consider the consequences of doing so. Do you want to do that when the *"Do you want to save your work before closing?"* dialog is showing. If you want to close no matter what then why not just call `ExitProcess()` and be done with it? Which is presumably what `exit()` does. What is the problem with that? It's not as if you seem to care about the state of your app when you decide to terminate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I typed it just off the top of my head. There's no unsaved data in the actual app and whatever is there, the user is aware of because there's an option/setting to close the app when the schedule is complete.

Comment: So just call `exit()` or `ExitProcess()` and be done. That seems the cleanest option to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If I do that the app doesn't have a chance to save its state, which is done from WM_DESTROY and WM_CLOSE for the main thread. I guess I can call all that stuff from a close-now method, I just don't feel good abort just terminating my process in case some dlls may be in use and such.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just tried calling `PostQuitMessage` from the main thread and it seems to do the trick for all windows, except File Open dialog. So speaking of "so long as they are coded correctly", why is it not obeying `WM_QUIT`?

Comment: How did you manage to call `PostQuitMessage` from the main thread when the file dialog was executing its modal message loop?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: On a timer from a worker thread, I post my own WM_APP message to the main window, which in turn calls `PostQuitMessage`. It closes all windows I listed above, except the one created with `CFileDialog::DoModal`. (I opened the Open File dialog from `WM_COMMAND` message invoked by a user interaction from the app's main menu.)

Comment: And is the file dialog's loop dispatching your timer message?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No. It's a waitable timer that is created by the worker thread that has nothing to do with the file dialog.

Comment: So how does the timer fire when the file dialog is in its modal message loop?

Comment: David, the timer is created using `CreateWaitableTimer` and later set using `SetWaitableTimer` after which the worker thread waits for it to become signaled using `WaitForSingleObject`, after which I do `::PostMessage(hMainWnd, WM_APP_MY_MSG, 0, 0);`. The main window then catches this message and does `PostQuitMessage`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `CFileDialog::DoModal` must be starting its own thread(s) to free up the main application thread. I can't explain it any other way... The question is why doesn't it obey `WM_QUIT`?

Comment: No, the file dialog window is run out of the calling thread. What is the problem with `exit()`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Well, somehow it does the job... partially. As for `exit()`, as I said, I don't want to mess up any loaded dlls by terminating my app.

Comment: When I post `WM_QUIT` on the main thread, my file dialog closes. I guess you are doing it wrong. Calling `exit()` will be fine. In what way are you going to mess up any DLLs. The process closes, the system reclaims any resources. It's all good. If you want to exit the process there and then with no user interaction, irrespective of the state of the app, then `exit()` or `ExitProcess()` are perfect for your needs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Read all the warnings for the `ExitProcess` and `TerminateProcess` APIs. I just don't want to end up with some weird DLL-related bug. Been there, done that. As for the file dialog, I don't do anything unusual with it. Like I said, I use the CFileDialog class and then call DoModal on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer, it depends on your app's architecture and what it's doing.  I don't quite understand why you would want to force close your application while it is in a common dialog, but if you do, then exit() is safe.  In that case the process is actually shutdown from the operating system's perspective as opposed to a forced termination (TerminateProcess).  In theory TerminateProcess might leave objects in the OS (DLL global data and such) in an inconsistent state, and exit() will be cleaner in that regard.

Generally though I'd avoid having visible UI that is up for the user just disappear and instead close the windows in reaction to some user choice.

But, exit() will work.

Comment: In a normal circumstance there will no common dialogs open. I'm just probing a situation when an end-user, say, leaves the app with the File Open, or some other dialog open.

Comment: `might leave objects in the OS (DLL global data and such)` - could you explain me exact reason of this? When calling `TerminateProcess`, operating system can clean up resources related to that process, can't it?

Comment: It depends on the architecture and design of the DLLs themselves.  When TerminateProcess is called the DLLs are not guaranteed to get the application disconnect events that go with normal shutdown.  Therefore DLLs that are shared between multiple processes might not clean up correctly.  This is noted in the MSDN documentation for TerminateProcess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exit() but a safer way to close the window would be:

SomewWindow->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

You could then destroy the window object or show the window later.

Comment: The question seems to be focused on the scenario of "close everything now, rather than "unwinding" the application.

Comment: @BitBlitz: Yes. Hiding a window is not what I need. I'm closing the application.